# Kate in Kubuntu 20.04 stops shutdown if fils is unsaved

Tags: kubuntu, kde, shutdown

Kate in Kubuntu 20.04 prompts every time for saving when system is trying shutdown, while a not saved file is there.
[Kshutdown](https://kshutdown.sourceforge.io/) shutdown the PC every evening past hour.

of this PC per month about 20 hours running. sometimes running a complete week.

How could shutdown anyway without prompting, and maybe (extra feature) restore the old files with next start?

#### System

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20
KDE Plasma Version: 5
```

Comment: I think if you shutdown using a cronjob, it might override kate.  But I'm not sure.  You can give it a try.  As for Kate, I think it can save sessions and reload them.  But for unsaved work, I guess that would be lost.

Comment: Protect unsaved work has no priority for me here.